# The comma operator in a declaration

Tags: c++

I am writing a C++ parser (actually a small subset of it) and can't find an explanation to why comma operator is not allowed in a variable initialization.

```
int a = 1, 2; // throws a "Expected ';' at the end of declaration" compiler error
a = 1, 2; // assigns the result of the comma binary operator to the a (2)
int a = (1, 2); // does the same as above, because paren expression is allowed as an initializer
```

The C++ spec says that you can use an expression as an initializer in a variable declaration. Why is comma binary expression not allowed but all the other expressions (with higher precedence) are allowed? cppreference.com (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) says that any expression can be used as an initializer.

Section 8.5 of the C++ spec says that initializer can contain assignment-expression only. Is this the place that regulates that assignment is the lowest-precedence expression allowed in the initialization?

Comment: You hate compiler writers? Where does that leave them when parsing this `int i = 1, 2, j = 3;`?

Comment: "Is this the place that regulates that assignment is the lowest-precedence expression allowed in the initialization?" Yes.

Comment: @n.m. but is there any reason why comma expression is not allowed?

Comment: Yes: in order to disambiguate with `int i = 2, j = 3`.

Comment: @n.m. oh, now I get it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The language grammar interprets commas in initializers as comma-delimited declarator clauses, i.e. of the form:

```
int i = 2, j = 3;
```

To avoid that ambiguity, you need to wrap comma-expressions in parentheses.

From **[dcl.decl]**:

```
[...]
init-declarator-list:
    init-declarator
    init-declarator-list , init-declarator
[...]
```

Comment: That means that you cannot use a comma operator as an initializer, but have to use the paren expression and paren expressions are allowed to have the comma subexpression.

Comment: @ElvissStrazdins - Sure, from the point of view of the grammar, that's true.  I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: initializer-list can be used only in braced-init-list, so this has nothing to do with my question. I am asking about the equal-initializer.

Comment: Let me take another look.  But in the meantime, it seems clear that you already know how to interpret the grammar definitions in the standard, so why are you asking this question?

Comment: The question was why the comma is not allowed in the initialization. But I already got the answer. It is so to disambiguate with "int i = 2, j = 3"

Comment: @ElvissStrazdins - I see.  Well, FWIW, I've updated my answer with what I believe is now the correct part of the grammar :)